# What stellar conditions and orbital distance are needed to produce a year length of 515 Earth days and 9 Earth hours on an Earthlike planet?

Tags: orbit, planet, exoplanet, habitable-zone, earth-like-planet

A planet has a year length of 515 Earth days and 9 Earth hours. It is the same size and has the same climate as Earth. What stellar conditions would be needed to produce this and what orbital distance is needed?

Answer (score 2):

We can estimate this using the [inverse square law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law) and the [mass-luminosity relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93luminosity_relation),
$$L=M^a$$
where $L$ is the luminosity of the star, and $M$ is its mass, both measured relative to the Sun. (That is, the mass and luminosity of the Sun = $1$). For a main sequence star of mass similar to the Sun $a\approx4$, for larger stars $a\approx3.5$. Please bear in mind that this is just an estimate, and that a star gets more luminous as it ages.

To keep things simple, let's assume that orbits are perfect circles. By the inverse square law, a planet with orbit radius $R$ orbiting a star of luminosity $L$ receives the same intensity of light and heat as the Earth if
$$R^2=L$$
where $R$ is measured in [astronomical units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit).

From [Kepler's 3rd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law),
$$R^3=MT^2$$
where $T$ is the orbital period in [sidereal years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_year).

Combining these equations we get
$$M=T^p$$
where
$$p=\frac{4}{3a-2}$$

Here are the results for $T=515.375$ days.

| a | 3.5 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mass | 1.175885 | 1.147652 |
| Lumin | 1.763102 | 1.734766 |
| Radius | 1.327818 | 1.317105 |

I calculated those results using this [Sage / Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdUmFv2jAQ_Y7Ef3jK1AkmGiAhUFAjbdK6LwNpCq32DeSSg1gEJ7OdVqjqf985brcxf7B07-6e7z1fEAT4Spb0SSqCLQjGCo2TMAarAcqG8cpIe8ZyAKFyVPpRWmiRy8Yg63bAZ19pCNSlUGSZQ1gUwngycSLIsqURVlYKnLgT2hYD33qQT6QgrYGROWkSJc7EA5SkDraAVMjF2YS-2N8rfMQSQpPLmqrk6kYxwwAZpHGgMFZXqjrJHdO1uQuCB0M8-iZGylyfcL-JPO7kMbNDNxAeey54KMRhgluWeItJK3bdqOtSHr1ZjtwXr4lQWFubxXBIKnyWR1lTLkVY6cPQRcMV-3p1F13djK7m8V9zt5rK1p53pp9aWsvGPJ7xY4Uok-qAaBTF4SgJo3G3EwSBK_2AL_9KfWCpTv_x1O2IhoWMJ_NkPruZjcKZL19fmPzmbrfTRiniKbMn03gau-rPUvFeiJ3tdnLaY9urScsqT5NxEsazhNchnfDV2Grb1LmwlH4TpaH-wku4Z0LfgWH7nIdrhieM9GK2XuAaUf_9W1Pu2aD24X__kHFofmnbW76V15rH6wXO0EUwwOoSXv6x1iUve_ZB1m7vAi_ZK1qfXjI3TLMIR_H-le0LLtm-U12Sxq6g3ZHpeHUGCFL3ql-f_m99w-qJ&lang=sage).

A star in that mass range is a heavy G-type star, or perhaps a light F-type star.

Comment: Stars (solar type stars on the main sequence) get more luminous as they age, the temperature is fairly constant.

Comment: What orbital distance is needed?

Comment: @Galactic Using a=4, the orbit radius is ~ 1.317 au ~= 197036000 km.

Comment: @PM2Ring, what about using a=3.5?

Comment: @Galactic Like the table says, for a=3.5, radius is ~ 1.328 au. If you want the value in km, please click on the script link. You don't need to install anything to run the script.

Comment: @PM2Ring to the rescue! For an "Earthlike planet" I wonder if it's the *fraction* of the luminosity that actually gets through the atmosphere, reaches the surface and is energetically useful for photosynthesis? In other words should there be some kind of "color penalty" that reduces $L$ to $L_{\text{useful}}$? Perhaps some exoplanetologist has done this long ago and it just needs to be looked up?

Comment: @uhoh Yes, there probably should be a colour correction, since the peak frequency of a more luminous star is higher. But this is only a crude estimate which ignores star age & metallicity. We only have good mass-luminosity data for a few hundred stars (mostly from nearby binary systems, see [DEBCat](https://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/jkt/debcat/)) to fit the mass-luminosity function to.